# looping through an array and breaking when switch statement condition is met

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, switch-statement

I am attempting to loop through an array of arrays, and for each array, I am running a function. This function has a switch statement that will alert the user if a condition is met. I want the loop to break instantly when an error is found (not 'good') Unfortunately, because this function is ran with each item in the array, the loop  will only count the last item's condition.

Here is where I am looping through the array:

```php
foreach($Array as $item){
        
    $Id = $item['data1'];
    $name = $item['data2'];
    $age = $item['data3'];

    if(!$Id){
        $con = 'id';
        errorHandler($con); 
    }else if (!$name){
        $con = 'name';
        errorHandler($con); 
    }else if (!age){
        $con = 'age';
        errorHandler($con); 
    }else{
        $con = 'good';
        errorHandler($con); 
    }
```

Here is the errorHandler function

```php
function errorHandler($con){

    switch($con){
    case 'id':
        $body = 'there was no id'
              break;
    case 'name':
        $body = 'there was no name'
              break;
    case 'age':
        $body = 'there was no age'
              break;
    case 'age':
        $body = 'all good'
              break;
        ?>
<h1><?php echo $body ?></h1>
<?php
    }
```

So basically as it loops through the array  if the last item in the array is equal to the final else condition ('good'), the 'all good' will be displayed, no matter what the other items were. Basically what is displayed to the user is whatever the condition of last item in the array is. I want the foreach to loop through the array, and instantly break if any condition other than 'good' is  met, and show the user the error.

The loop shouldn't even get to the last item if anything other than 'good' is met.

I think it's to do with the function being called for every item in the loop but I can't figure it out.

How can I fix my code so that if the user hits any condition other than the 'good', the switch statement shows the error and stops the loop?

Comment: "The loop shouldn't even get to the last item [...]": so prove that claim to yourself. If you have code, you either know what it does, or you don't and you need to find out what it does. There is no "should", only "you have some debugging left to do". Form [mcve] code that includes the input that you see things going wrong for, and then step through that code. Why is it doing what you see it do?

Comment: You have lots of syntax errors. Missing `}`, no `;` at the end of the `$body` assignments.

Answer (score -1):

`errorHandler()` should return a boolean that indicates whether there was an error. Then you can check this in `foreach` and break out of the loop.

```
function errorHandler($con) {
    $body = '';
    switch($con) {
    case 'id':
        $body = 'there was no id';
        break;
    case 'name':
        $body = 'there was no name';
        break;
    case 'age':
        $body = 'there was no age';
        break;
    case 'age':
        $body = 'all good';
        break;
    }
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $body ?></h1>
    <?php
    return $body != '';
}

foreach ($Array as $item) {
        
    $Id = $item['data1'];
    $name = $item['data2'];
    $age = $item['data3'];

    if (!$Id) {
        $con = 'id';
        if (errorHandler($con)) {
            break;
        }; 
    } elseif (!$name) {
        $con = 'name';
        if (errorHandler($con)) {
            break;
        }; 
    } elseif (!$age) {
        $con = 'age';
        if (errorHandler($con)) {
            break;
        }; 
    } else {
        $con = 'good';
        if (errorHandler($con)) {
            break;
        }; 
    }
    echo "UserId $Id, Name = $name, Age = $age<br>";
}
```

Comment: `$Id`, `$name`, and `$age` are single-use variables and should be avoided as unnecessary code bloaters.